# Whole house dehumidifier- freestanding vs vented

Tags: hvac, ducts, dehumidifier

I’m considering the purchase of a Dehumidifier for our basement, to avoid mustiness in the unfinished/unconditioned portion. I want a nicer quality HVAC-grade unit, both for energy-usage reasons and because I’m not impressed with the quality of hardware-store freestanding models (plastic-box on cheap wheels.. you know the kind.)

Looking at something HVAC-grade like the “Aprilaire 1850” or “Santa Fe Impact” — and there are other good ones too — I see that sometimes they come in **Freestanding and Ducted** models.

Am I correct that the only difference (e.g. between the 1850 and 1850F) is the plastic “fluting” to accept HVAC ducting, and a small difference in price?

If so, is there any reason why I **wouldn’t** want the duct-able version? That way if I wanted to attach it into the HVAC system later, I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed dehumidifiers in the past. The only difference I saw was that free standing models have a catch basin.

The built-in models require a drain or a pump in the tray, to pump the water to a drain, but otherwise, they work the same way.

For ducted models using the pressure of your HVAC system, there is a flow switch to start the compressor when the blower fan is running in "heat mode".